# Ubuntu partition not found

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, bootloader

Before the last shutdown of Ubuntu 20.04 my storage space of disk was very low, then after starting my laptop this error occurs.

```
Error: no partition found
Cannot read or write outside partition
```

When I enter into the command line by pressing the `c` key grub> loads, but on giving commands like ls, cd, sudo, etc. it says `error: can't find command...`

After pressing the power button, the first thing that comes to the screen is `error: no such partition`, four times the same sentence is repeated, and at the end `Press any key to continue` On pressing any key, some options appear.

- Ubuntu
- Advanced options for Ubuntu
- Memory test

but all results to reload the boot but no results. On restarting sometimes this kernel panic screen also appears.

[image]

Another time it goes until **ubuntu** logo appears after which login field to appear but after logo, immediately black screen appears saying

> /dev/sda4: clean, 1500298/7749632 files, 29454730/30995712 blocks

And nothing happens, until I press power button and it shutdowns

Comment: I would boot a *live* system (eg. Ubuntu install media) and do a *file system check* (ie. `fsck`).  If errors are detected & fixed, I'd expect your system to boot normally next login.

Comment: Oky, thanks. I will give it a try and inform you the outcome

Comment: Found that, that was due to low storage. I use Ubuntu live usb to free up storage and now its working

Comment: That may be, but in my case I found an easy solution. I just make the usb bootable and load the ubuntu live, the mount my disk /dev/sda4 into /mnt and delete some stuff to clear up some storage. This worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to low storage, after access the machine via live Ubuntu usb freed up some storage and now its working.